# Suppose $a,b∈\mathbb{R}$ use proof by contrapositive to show the following implication is true $b^3+ba^2\leq a^3+ab^2 \Rightarrow b\leq a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, inequality

Suppose  $\{a,b\}\subset \mathbb{R}$ use proof by contraposition to show the following implication is true :
$$b^3+ba^2\leq a^3+ab^2 \Rightarrow b\leq a$$

using contraposition  me is we start $a \leq b$

Comment: Hint: $\;a^3+ab^2-ba^2-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+b^2)\,$. As for the `proof-verification` tag, *which* proof?

Comment: In your title you say you want to prove $a\leq b$.  In your body you say that you want to prove $b\leq a$.  Which is it?  Whichever it is, remember that when using proof by contraposition we want to begin with the *negation* of what we wanted to prove and that the negation of $x\leq y$ is $x>y$ (*strict inequality here*).

Comment: @JMoravitz..sorry i edited now

Comment: Contrapositive seems unnecessary.  If $b^3+ba^2 \leq a^3 + ab^2$ then it follows that $b^3 \leq a^3$ from which it follows $b\leq a$.  But also, you've incorrectly stated what the assumption of the contrapositive would be.  You would assume $a < b$ and then prove $a^3 + ab^2 < b^3+ba^2$.

Comment: @Addem,,,YEA..thank you since a<b then $a^3<b^3$ but how to prove $ab^2<ba^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $ab=0$ it's obvious.

Let $ab\neq0$ and  $b>a$.

Thus, $$b^3+a^2b-a^3-ab^2=(b-a)(a^2+b^2)>0.$$
We got a contradiction.